# Receiving results from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am using the following code to create 10 threads. I expect to receive different random numbers from my threads and print them. but the results are the same.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "C.h"
#include "BB.h"
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>

void initiazer(std::promise<int> * promObj, int i)
{

    std::cout << "Inside Thread " <<i<< std::endl;     
    (promObj)->set_value((rand() % 100) + 1);
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    std::promise<int> promiseObj[10];
    std::future<int> futureObj [10];
    std::thread th[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {       
        futureObj[i] = promiseObj[i].get_future();
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        th[i] = std::thread(initiazer,&promiseObj[i],i) ;
        std::cout << futureObj[i].get() << std::endl;       
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        th[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `futureObj[i].get()` will block until the thread you just launched finishes.

Answer (score 2):

`rand()` is not threadsafe, see https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand.  Use the more modern functions defined in `random` instead, e.g.

```
std::random_device rd;
auto seed = rd ();
std::mt19937 mt (seed);
....
auto random_number = mt ();
```

**Edit:**

As others have pointed out, `mt19937::operator ()` is not guaranteed to be threadsafe either.  Better then, as suggested by n.m., to create one of these objects per thread as the updated live demo now shows.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ukDulOnGX8mhiHM)

Comment: @PeteBecker `std::mt19937` is a type. Why wouldn't it be thread-safe, and what would it mean?

Comment: @PeteBecker In that case I guess it has to be protected by a mutex (or invoked only on a single thread).

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm pretty sure that having a separate `std::mt19937` object for each thread would suffice. Of course one needs to seed each one differently to get different values (the default random_device will normally the job).

Comment: @PaulSanders -- mutex or single thread would also work for `rand()`. There is a better answer, as another comment shows. But I get **really annoyed** when people recommend "the more modern functions" without understanding what they can and can't do. Knee jerk reactions are not proper design.

Comment: @PeteBecker This was not a knee-jerk reaction. I check cppreference for race conditions before suggesting using these functions and none are specified, but I like n.m's idea better as it is guaranteed to work and have updated my answer accordingly.